# Find which highlighting is being used for a particular string in Vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to debug a syntax file with a few hundred `syntax` and `highlight` commands, many of which with the same result.

I want to know which of these are being applied to a particular string to decide how to colour it.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/interactively-check-given-string-highlight-group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in [Vi Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/interactively-check-given-string-highlight-group) (thanks @mkrieger1 for the link).

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```